# Extract date from AWS Cloudwatch insights

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to extract `date_from` and `date_to` from the following log field value.
`date_from=11-04-2020&date_to=01-04-2021&page_size=1000&page=1` in AWS cloudwatch

I have so far tried `parse` keyword with the following regex `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` and it does not work.

What I ultimately want to do is extract these two dates and gets the time difference between them in days.

Here's the query I tried,

`filter @logStream like /<log-stream>/ and process like /rest-call/ | parse parameters '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}' as @date | display @date`

Comment: Try `parse parameters /date_from=(?<date_from>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*?date_to=(?<date_to>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/ | display date_from, date_to`

Comment: What @Wiktor said and <@date_from> and <@date_to> so u can use them later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture both `date_from` and `date_to` into two [named capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

```sql
parse parameters /date_from=(?<date_from>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*?date_to=(?<date_to>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/ | display date_from, date_to
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PNS6yt/1).

If the date format can be any, you may replace the `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` specific pattern with a more generic `[^&]+`:

```sql
/date_from=(?<date_from>[^&]+).*?date_to=(?<date_to>[^&]+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PNS6yt/2).

Note that `.*?` matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (it is necessary to make sure the regex engine can "travel" all the way from the first capture to the second one as the regex engine parses the string from left to right and can never "skip" parts of a string, it should *consume* them).

Comment: Yes, this worked for the capturing part. Any idea on how to get the time difference in days? Can I use toMillis() function and then subtract?

Comment: @turingMan Once you obtained the variables, you may use them with whatever function that suits you.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think there is a built in AWS function to convert a date (dd-mm-yyyy) to a timestamp :/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking AWS does not currently have any Date time functions to convert a date (i.e - mm/dd/yyyy) to a timestamp. Therefore, I exported the results of the above query to a CSV and did the timestamp calculations in Google Sheets.